# Criar um nó dentro de outro no Firebase com Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, android-fragment, firebase-database

Gostaria de criar um nó chamado "Posts" dentro de cada usuário, mas só consigo criar fora do usuário. Poderia me ajudar a criar o nó dentro do usuario?

Aqui está o exemplo de como queria que ficasse o "Posts" no firebase e como está:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o codigo Android que cria o "Posts":

```
    private void addPost(Post post) {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Posts").push();

    String key = myRef.getKey();
    post.setPostKey(key);

    myRef.setValue(post).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            showMessage("Adicionado com sucesso");
            popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            popAddPost.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: João. De uma reformulada na pergunta de forma que a mesma expresse de fato o sua dúvida. Da forma que você pôs não fica claro o que você quer, na verdade soa como se você tivesse querendo que alguém completasse o código, o que não bate com o intuito do SO.

Comment: ok, reformulada, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

João, para que o nó seja criado dentro do usuário você deve referencia-lo no local correto, tente usar o seguinte código:

```html
 private void addPost(Post post) {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.child('Users').child(USER_ID).child("Posts").push();

    String key = myRef.getKey();
    post.setPostKey(key);

    myRef.setValue(post).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            showMessage("Adicionado com sucesso");
            popupClickProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            popupAddBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            popAddPost.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema

Comment: Magina, você entendeu onde estava o problema João?

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito!!! Resolvido

Comment: Sim, estava esquecendo de referenciar o caminho

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :D